# How to remove space on the side of the two containers?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a clone of the twitter sign-in page and everything was functioning properly thus far until without me making any change what so-ever, space appeared on the side of the two containers and I'm unsure how to remove it?

I will link an image below of the site in an attempt to supplement my poor explaination
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56iOZ.jpg)

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-l">
                <svg
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                style="width: 300px"
                aria-hidden="true"
                class="r-jwli3a r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-rxcuwo r-1777fci r-m327ed r-dnmrzs r-494qqr r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr"
            >
                <g>
                    <path
                        fill="#ffffff"
                        d="M23.643 4.937c-.835.37-1.732.62-2.675.733.962-.576 1.7-1.49 2.048-2.578-.9.534-1.897.922-2.958 1.13-.85-.904-2.06-1.47-3.4-1.47-2.572 0-4.658 2.086-4.658 4.66 0 .364.042.718.12 1.06-3.873-.195-7.304-2.05-9.602-4.868-.4.69-.63 1.49-.63 2.342 0 1.616.823 3.043 2.072 3.878-.764-.025-1.482-.234-2.11-.583v.06c0 2.257 1.605 4.14 3.737 4.568-.392.106-.803.162-1.227.162-.3 0-.593-.028-.877-.082.593 1.85 2.313 3.198 4.352 3.234-1.595 1.25-3.604 1.995-5.786 1.995-.376 0-.747-.022-1.112-.065 2.062 1.323 4.51 2.093 7.14 2.093 8.57 0 13.255-7.098 13.255-13.254 0-.2-.005-.402-.014-.602.91-.658 1.7-1.477 2.323-2.41z"
                    ></path>
                </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="container-r">
                asddsas
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh; 
    display: flex
}

.container-l {
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url('./twitterbackground.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container-l svg {
    width: 400px;
    fill: white;
}

.container-r {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}`
```

Comment: i think there is a container-fluid class on bootstrap that makes its width 100%

Answer (score 0):

I'm did some mock that solves your problem.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container1"></div>
    <div class="container2"></div>
</div>
```

In the above HTML the `.container` contains two class `.container1 & .container2` which shares 50% of the page equally.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;

}
.container1{
    flex: 0.5;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.container2{
    flex: 0.5;
    background-color: rgb(201, 164, 119);
}
```

Please like the answer if you found this useful.